# I have problems with methods store -- /usr/lib/apt/methods/store

Tags: command-line, package-management, updates, compiling

I can't do `sudo apt update` because I have problems with the package `apt-transport-store`. When I try to install this package, I get an error that says it can't be found.

[image: error when trying to install package]

Comment: Please post the output from the failed `sudo apt update` command; add to your question, please.

Comment: I already added the picture but it is in spanish

Comment: Not sure why the error is mentioning a non-existent package. According to `apt-file search`, this should be part of apt.

Comment: You tend to get English output if you prepend a command with LANG=C, e.g. `LANG=C sudo apt update`